# Automatically overflow list when container exceeds maximum height

Tags: html, css

**Setup:**
Let's say that I have a simple modal which must always be at the very bottom of the page and cover the entire width of the page. Structure of this modal looks like so:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="container">
      <p>Sample text</p>
      <ul>
          <li>
          ...
          <li>
      </ul>
      <button>Sample button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This modal also has some **max-height**, let's say `90vh` (10vh is reserved for something that i always want to have visible from under the modal). Worth mentioning that none of the elements inside this modal have fixed height.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**
I want to show overflow on **ul** whenever maximum height on container is exceeded.
I've tried a lot of different approaches but none of them worked, and for now i have max-height on my **ul** set to calc(90vh - [total height of all elements except **ul**]). I calculate this total height summing margins, paddings, font sizes etc. but I see it's really bad approach, because when f.e text on my button changes to 3 lines then everything breaks.

Comment: "I want to show overflow on ul" : what do you mean ? Show a scroll or hide overflow content ?

Comment: show the scroll

Answer (score 0):

**where is the CSS codes?**

you can use

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10vh 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  max-height: 80vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
    <p>I am content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```